# Integral of an exponential of rational expression of the argument form $\dfrac{a}{x} + bx$

Tags: special-functions, bessel-functions, rational-functions

I wish to compute the integral of

$$\displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{x^2} \exp{\left(-\dfrac{a}{x}-bx\right)} dx$$

I found something similar in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik 7th Ed. p336 (Sec 3.324) in terms of the modified Bessel function of the second kind $K_\nu (x)$ but it didn't include the factor of $\dfrac{1}{x^2}$.

Can you help? Thank you.

Comment: Hint: use the change of variable $y:=\dfrac 1x$ to get the G&R formula

Comment: Perform the change of integration variables from $x$ to $t$ via $t = bx$ and use [$(10.32.10)$](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E10) to deduce $$
b\int_0^{ + \infty } {\exp \left( { - t - \frac{{ab}}{t}} \right)\frac{{{\rm d}t}}{{t^2 }}}  = 2\sqrt {\frac{b}{a}} \frac{1}{2}\left( {\frac{1}{2}2\sqrt {ab} } \right)\int_0^{ + \infty } {\exp \left( { - t - \frac{{(2\sqrt {ab} )^2 }}{{4t}}} \right)\frac{{{\rm d}t}}{{t^{1 + 1} }}} \\ = 2\sqrt {\frac{b}{a}} K_1 (2\sqrt {ab} ).
$$